# c# home works can't solve

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop, int

I have to make console program that asks the user to enter number, then the program has to make square of stars (*) equal to the number that the user input.

```
Console.WriteLine("enter number and press ENTER"); 
int userNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
int rowNumber = 0; 
int lineNumber = 0; 
int counter = 0; 
while(counter < userNumber) { 
    Console.Write("*"); 
        while(lineNumber < userNumber) { 
            Console.WriteLine("*"); 
            lineNumber++; 
        }
     counter++; 
 } 
 Console.WriteLine();
```

example:

```
user input :5
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
*****
```

Comment: Show us what code you have so far.

Comment: Start by creating a console program, your teacher should have shown you how, now get the input from the user, again this should have been shown in class.  Give it a shot and come back with where you are stuck. IE code something and we can then help, especially since its homework and you will learn nothing if we do it for oyu.

Comment: i know how to make the input and the program , even succed to create two of the border of the square but cant make the other.

Comment: Console.WriteLine("enter number and press ENTER");
            int userNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int rowNumber = 0;
            int lineNumber = 0;
            int counter = 0;
            while(counter < userNumber)
            {
                
                Console.Write("*");
                while(lineNumber < userNumber)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("*");
                    lineNumber++;
                }
                counter++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

Comment: Adding the code you wrote would help those who want to provide you a good answer. You may even learn good tricks...

Comment: Better add the code to the question (edit it) and say at which point you got a problem. What is not working and what to you try to do in your program.

Comment: Please do not add information to your question in the comments; it's easy to miss in the clutter. Instead, [edit] your question to do so, where you can properly format it and it can be seen. (You can also find the edit link right below the tags in the question itself.)

Comment: @satis I edited the code that you posted in a comment into your question but you should review it for accuracy.

Comment: And what doesn't work with that? What error are you getting?

Comment: For 26 minutes this question let me wonder if SO users today just were in a extraordinarily good mood. Then the downvoting squad came, probably called by a flag, and now I guess that closure is inevitable. Sorry satis you also have to learn to formulate good questions and here on SO you better produce good questions right from the beginning. You don't have much time to improve.

Comment: @Trilarion You say that sarcastically, but yes, people *are* expected to have reasonably good questions when they post them here.  We don't want people just throwing crap at a wall and seeing what sticks.  There are plenty of opportunities for people to fix the questions that they post, or to learn from those experiences in the future.  Refraining from providing the feedback that a question is problematic only results in more bad questions, and no incentive for anyone to improve.

Comment: @Servy I know and acknowledge that although I also think it is debatable how strong the feedback must be in order to achieve a positive effect. You see here several attempts at improving the question but you also see an avalanche like effect of flaging. Those who spent a lot of time here in this ecosystem should not forget that this is all new to people right after registration.

Comment: it working but i cant make it do all the borders of the square

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do the following:

**explanation for the code:**

Square is formed of 2 equal sides, so in order to draw the square using *, you will think of it like a matrix

you need a loop to draw the rows and another loop to draw the columns, and both loop has upper limit which is the number entered by the user.

the rule of drawing is like this i will put star if i am in the first row or the last one or in the first column or last, so by addressing this i used the if statement ( i==0 || i== number-1 || j==0 || j== number -1) where i is the row and j is the column, and if this condition is not satisfied, print space

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number:");
        var number=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for(int i=0; i < number; i++)
        {           
            for(int j=0; j < number; j++)
            {           
                if(i==0 || i == number-1 || j==0 || j == number-1)
                    Console.Write("*"); 
                else
                    Console.Write(" ");
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

here a working [DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jLFvuR)

hope this will help you

Comment: I am sure his teacher if he catches you, he will say thank you in bad way :)

Comment: thanks its really short code i will try now to deeply understand how its works.

Comment: @satis if you need any help, go ahead, i am ready to answer you, click the DEMO and see the sample in action, also i added some notes there, hope it will help you

Comment: @satis, if the my answer was enough, please mark it as answer and up vote it, thank you in advance

Comment: it good answer i marked it , thanks.